# Widget on iOS 17 Beta device - Adopt containerBackground API

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit, xcode15, ios17

I'm working on an app + widget with Xcode 15 Beta. The widget works as expected on iOS 17 Beta simulators, but when running on my device with iOS 17 beta, it displays "Please adopt containerBackground API" instead of the desired content.

[image]

I searched around, and could only find `containerBackground` on [LocationButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocationui/locationbutton/4195631-containerbackground), but I'm not using Core Location at all. Can anybody point out why it is referred here?

Comment: I believe it may be referring to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/containerBackground(_:for:)

Comment: @ScottM Yes indeed. Could yo add your reply as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The modifier in question is [`.containerBackground(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/containerBackground(_:for:)), which is new in iOS 17 and related platform versions.

With it you can specify the background for your entire widget as a modifier to your custom view, e.g.:

```swift
VStack {
  Text("My widget")
    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
}
.containerBackground(.red.gradient, for: .widget)
```

Note that in some places, e.g., if your widget displays in the new StandBy mode, the container background may not display at all.

You can customise this behaviour by adding the modifier [`containerBackgroundRemovable(false)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/widgetconfiguration/containerbackgroundremovable(_:)) – although that may prevent your widget from being shown at all in some contexts.

A preferable option is to subscribe to the environment variable [`\.showsWidgetContainerBackground`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/showswidgetcontainerbackground/) to tweak your widget if you're in a context where the background is not showing.

More details can be found in the WWDC video [Bringing widgets to new places.](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10027)

Comment: For a widget that is only used as a Lock Screen Widget would ` .widgetBackground(backgroundView: Color.clear)` be appropriate? 

Comment: I don't have a VStack, I have a ZStack, inside a GeometryReader, inside a Body, and adding this modifier didnt work for me!

Answer (score 63):

Great Filip Němeček [article here](https://nemecek.be/blog/192/hotfixing-widgets-for-ios-17-containerbackground-padding) on adapting a hot fix for this so it still works on iOS16 devices.

TLDR:

Add an extension with the OS check:

```
extension View {
    func widgetBackground(_ backgroundView: some View) -> some View {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
            return containerBackground(for: .widget) {
                backgroundView
            }
        } else {
            return background(backgroundView)
        }
    }
}
```

Add `widgetBackground` to all of your different widgets (pick your background view/color, of course):

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // widget content
    }
    .widgetBackground(Color.black)
}
```

Also, he mentions an interesting note about iOS17 widgets, where they force additional margin padding on your design.

You can disable this while generating WidgetConfiguration:

```
var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    //IntentConfiguration stuff
    .contentMarginsDisabled()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion William, I was able to mitigate this issue. Just adding some, if you have compilation error with #available check above try using this one:
`if #available(iOS 17, macCatalyst 17, *) `

Comment: Where (in what file/class) do you put extension View?

Context/location isn't clear.

Comment: @ErikaElectra I don't think this matters very much. It's kind of like declaring a global variable so you can put it anywhere. The cleanest way is probably make a new file swift called "View+Extensions.swift" and dump it in there but for my project I just threw it at the top of one of my WidgetView files.